# The limit as $n\to \infty$ of $\sin(1/x)^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus

I was trying to solve a question from my homework that was find if:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\sin(1/n)$$
Converges or diverges.

So I applied the root test and simplified to: $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sin(1/x)^
{1/x} $$

I looked at this limit on wolfram alpha and it goes to $1$ via some exponential rearranging then the application of l'Hospital rule.  But in order to determine whether it diverges or converges I need to know if the limit approaches 1 strictly from above.  But I have no idea if it does or how to check on wolfram alpha besides graphing it with something like desmos.

I know I can check the original series with the ratio test I am just practicing using the root test.

Comment: your limit is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x$ because near zero $\sin(x)\sim x$.

Comment: Maybe find the first few terms of its Taylor expansion...?

Comment: @Masacroso I don't really see how the observation helps, also can you give me some more information on sin(x) ~ x for values near zero? I think that might help me create some rationalizations for simplifying limits.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$n\sin\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac1n}\to 1$$

thus the series diverges.

Note also that

$$\sin(1/x)\le \frac1x\implies [x\sin(1/x)]^{1/x}\le 1$$

and thus the ratio test is is [genuinely inconclusive](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Root_test#In_limit_superior_form).

Comment: I agree it makes more sense to do this or the ratio test, and hadn't thought of just trying the divergence test, however, I am just looking at what to do if the root test isn't working simply.  So i'm doing a bunch of problems with the root test even if it isn't as easy.

Comment: I've edited the asnwer to address this point.

Answer (score 1):

$ n \sin (1/n)= \frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n} \to 1 \ne 0$ as $n \to \infty$, hence the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \sin(1/n)$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Starting points:

set $u = \frac{1}{x}$

And so our limit becomes

$L = \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \sin(u)^{u}$

Take the natural log, ie.,

$\ln(L) = \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \ln\left[\sin(u)^{u}\right] = \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} u\ln\left[\sin(u)\right] = \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln\left[\sin(u)\right]}{\frac{1}{u}} = \frac{-\infty}{\infty}$

Apply L'Hopitals!

$\ln(L) = \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{\cos(u)}{\sin(u)}}{\frac{-1}{u^{2}}} = \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{-u^{2}\cos(u)}{\sin(u)} = \frac{0}{0}$

Apply L'hopitals again!

$\ln(L) = \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{-2u\cos(u) + -u^{2}.-\sin(u) }{\cos(u)} = \frac{0 + 0}{1} = 0$

and so

$\ln(L) = 0 \rightarrow L = e^{0} = 1$

Thus

$L = \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \sin(u)^{u} = 1$

And thus, the series is divergent.

Comment: For the root test if L=1 L has to approach 1 strictly from above 1 else it is inconclusive.  I saw what you just showed on wolfram alpha, but I don't know how to determine if L is approaching strictly from the positive side of the limit.